# It is possible to get linker script symbols addresses as compile time constant values in C code?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, linker-scripts, bare-metal

I want to get the address of the end of my program and check at compilation/linker time if I have enough space, after the code, to place some random data in execution time.

But as the symbols provided by PROVIDE keyword are like normal variables in C code, I can not verify it in compilation time.

In the linker script I have the symbol :

```
PROVIDE (__data_end_rom   = _etext + SIZEOF (.data));
```

So I can use this symbol to get the address of the end of my code :

```
extern u16 __data_end_rom;
```

I can calculate the available memory if I suppose the end address to be 0xffff:

```
#define AVAILABLE_MEM (0Xffff - &__data_end_rom)
```

And I was thinking to check the available memory with _Static_assert(cond, message) provided in gcc 4.6

```
_Static_assert(SIZE_I_WANT_TO_ASSURE <= AVAILABLE_MEM, "NOT ENOUGH MEMORY!!!");
```

My problem is : The macro AVAILABLE_MEM is not calculated at compilation time, so I get the error:

```
error: expression in static assertion is not constant
```

Is there any way to provide the __data_end_rom address directly in a label or in another way ?

I know that I can't get it in compilation time because the symbol will just be linked in the linker time, so there is some way to make the linker fails ?

I could check this directly in the linker script but I prefer not doing so because the SIZE_I_WANT_TO_ASSURE is another macro calculated from others macros in a configuration header.

Comment: The value of the linker variable will not be filled in until link time, while static assertions are normally done at compilation time. So it will not be possible to do it from code inside the actual program.

Comment: I know, but there is no way to make the linker fails? Or some command I can pass to the linker?

Comment: Check [the manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands). I'm sure you can find something there...

Comment: You can add a check to your linker script.  See *Gnu ld's* [ASSERT](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/ld/Miscellaneous-Commands.html).

Comment: The problem of reserving space in a variable like int8_t buffer[SIZE_I_WANT_TO_ASSURE] is that I won't be able to use all the available space in flash, the SIZE_I_WANT_TO_ASSURE is the minimum size I must have, but if I have more space I want to use it.
Thanks anyway, I decided to hack the linker script then.

Comment: @Lilás If you managed to "hack the linker script" to do this, can you share in an answer?

Comment: sorry, since this was 10 years ago I don't recall what I did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
_Static_assert(SIZE_I_WANT_TO_ASSURE <= AVAILABLE_MEM, "NOT ENOUGH MEMORY!!!");

error: expression in static assertion is not constant
```

The problem here is that you are trying to compare a "constant" generated during the linking phase of the build, in an expression that requires a compile time constant (that is, something the COMPILER knows during compilation).

```
#define AVAILABLE_MEM (0Xffff - &__data_end_rom)
```

The compiler won't know the address of `__data_end_rom`, only the linker knows that.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to do this at compile time, make the compiler tell you the data is too large. On the other hand, an additional script reading the binary file (e.g. using `size yourprog` in conjunction with a little bit of `awk` or something) should be able to provide the relevant information in the `makefile` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know why the compiler won't kwon the address of __data_end_rom, but I was wondering if I could write something in the code to the linker, and not to the compiler, something like : #linker ASSERT(SIZE(.text) + SIZE(.data) < 20k ).
As I think there is nothing like this, so I am going to hack the linker script, thanks.

Comment: @Lilás That's right, the compiler don't really know much about what the linker actually does - it just knows how to call the linker. Linker scripts aren't that bad. If you run `gcc -v myprog.c` it will show you what the default linker script looks like. So you can make a copy of that and add your line(s) to the copied file, and use the copy.

Comment: @Lilás This is quite old, but you may alternatively define `AVAILABLE_MEM` in the linker command file and this would work fine. This is not unreasonable either, as the linker script is specific to the target platform anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a custom linker script that has assertions in it. see here

http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Miscellaneous-Commands.html

you want to use the 'ASSERT' mechanism.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is a solution of the problem in linking time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the link script itself, something like this:

```
/* minimum amount of data required at end of .text */
_Min_Data_Left 0Xffff;

.text : 
{
... all the usual stuff ...
PROVIDE (__data_end_rom  = . );
. = . + _Min_Data_Left;
. = ALIGN(4);
} >FLASH
```

The linker will now tell you that FLASH has overflowed if you go over the limit - and compilation will fail, which I understand is what you want.

It's a commonly used method to ensure a minimum amount of stack and heap is available. Here's one version - look for _Min_Heap_Size and _Min_Stack_Size: https://github.com/pingdynasty/OwlWare/blob/master/Source/flash.ld

Out of curiosity, what will you do with the extra space in .text - I'm assuming this is in Flash?

Comment: OP wants it as a compile time constant, and I think it is impossible as Mats mentioned.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but the data that I want to know fits follows a format that is defined in C (practically, a big struct). So, I know what I need from C (sizeof, kind of), and know the room I have in the memory area (LENGTH(area)) in the linker script. Ideally, I'd send the required data size from the compiler/compiled code to the linker, so that the linker could fail.