# How can I make sure that my struct fits in a memory area defined in a linker script?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I'm having a problem very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835417/it-is-possible-to-get-linker-script-symbols-addresses-as-compile-time-constant-v), but no answer there is helping me. Building with gcc on ARM Cortex M4.

I have:

- a memory area defined in a linker script
- a complex structure, the size of which is computed and stored in a define in a header file

I would like:

- a compile or link time error, if that structure does not fit in the memory area.

I tried (like the person asking the question I linked to above):

- importing linker symbols with `extern uint8_t __AreaStart[];` and `extern uint8_t __AreaEnd[];` from the linker script. No compile time error, which makes sense since the values in the Area symbols are not known at compile time.

I could see:

- making ASSERTS in the linker script, but that would mean giving the size of the struct to the linker, and I'm not sure how to do that. For one, the size is currently in a pre-processor macro, not in an actual C symbol (it would be neat not to spend actual memory for communicating size from C to the linker).
- giving the `struct` type to the linker, so if I could get the equivalent of `sizeof(type)` in the linker script.
- actually defining a variable of that type in the memory area, in the C file. If it doesn't fit, the linker should complain. The problem is that this area holds user data, and needs to stay untouched over reprogramming. It cannot be part of the final binary, or user data would get overwritten. I could make an additional separate application just for the sake of checking, but I feel there must be a simpler solution (as of today, the Area does not even have a Section. Maybe add a `NOLOAD` section there?).

How should I go about failing at building, knowing that the size of the struct is available in a macro, generated at each build?

Background: the struct is generated by protobuf, that's why the size is considered variable. Maybe I could make the check after generating the `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to create a section in the Area in the linker script:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .config_no_load (NOLOAD) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.config_no_load*);
    KEEP(*(.config_no_load))
  } > CONFIG1
}
```

`KEEP` is required to avoid optimization of the unused memory. `CONFIG1` is the Area:

```
MEMORY
{
/* ... */
/* Configuration areas (App data) */
  CONFIG1 (rx) :     ORIGIN = 0x000f6000, LENGTH = 0x0100

}
```

Then in the C code, define a variable that is too large:

```c
__attribute__((section(".config_no_load"))) __attribute__((unused))
static uint8_t volatile fake_config_header[0x200] = {0};
```

results in error as such:

```
  LD        application.elf
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: application.elf section `.config_no_load' will not fit in region `CONFIG1'
```